# How can I make a variable (preferably boolean) that can determine whether or not a function is running?

Tags: unity-game-engine, boolean, unityscript

**CONTEXT**

I'm making a unity game and I need to test if my player is on the ground or not, for any of you familiar with things like "OnCollisionEnter", they won't work with the way make game functions, however, "OnControllerColliderHit" works, but there is no negative/exit for this.

What I want to do is have a boolean equal true while the function is running, and once the function has stopped being called (the player is not on the ground), this boolean would turn false.

Feel free to ask if you need any additional information, or (if you are knowledgeable in unity) find a different solution regarding "OnCollisionEnter".

Thanks!

Comment: You can just use an overlapping sphere to check for the ground? Physics.overlapsphere I think it is

Answer (score 1):

if your problem is checking if the character is on the ground you can make a `raycast` from your character down to the ground and we add a margin for uneven
platforms you should change this value and find the one that best suits your
ground

```
float distanceToGround;
float margin;

 void Start(){
   // get the distance to ground
   distanceToGround = collider.bounds.extents.y;
 }

  boolean IsGrounded() {
   return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, distanceToGround +  margin);
 }

 void Update () {
   if (IsGrounded()){
     //DoSomething
   }
 }
```

also if your character got a `character controller` component attached(as you are using `OnControllerColliderHit` so it is definitely attached ) you can simply check grounded like this

```
    void Start(){
         CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
      }

 void Update() {       
        if (controller.isGrounded)
            //DoSomething      
    }
```